# Find angle in triangle with given perimeter

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Given triangle $ABC$ with perimeter $P=25$. If $O$ is the center of inscribed circle and $CO=4$, prove that angle $C=60^0$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Cosine law for $c$ and Pithagorean theorem for $r$, $(p-c)$ and 4, but in this way I got 3 equations with 4 unknown values.

Comment: But you are not new to the site and you know you should add all the details of your attempt in the body of the question to avoid downvotes and votes to close.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I did not want to give a possible wrong direction to anybody.

Comment: @kmitov pythagorean theorem for $r,\frac{p}{2}-c,4 ?$

Comment: I use $p$ to denote $p=P/2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

A counterexample.

Let $c=9$, $a=8+\tfrac47\sqrt{21}$, $b=8-\tfrac47\sqrt{21}$.

Then
\begin{align}
\rho&=\tfrac12(a+b+c)=\frac{25}2
,\\
S&=\tfrac14\sqrt{4a^2b^2-(a^2+b^2-c^2)^2}
=\frac{25}4\sqrt{15}
,\\
r&=\frac S\rho
=\tfrac12\sqrt{15}
,\\
|IC|&=\sqrt{r^2+(\rho-c)^2}
=4
.
\end{align}

So, the conditions $P=25$ and $|IC|=4$ hold,
but

\begin{align}
\cos C&=
\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab}
=\frac{17}{32}
\ne\frac12
,
\end{align}

hence, the angle $C\ne60^\circ$.

Comment: Thank you very much g.kov, for the nice counterexample.

Comment: @kmitov: It's the same well-known 
[Heron’s formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula),
just one of its variations, expressed in terms of $a^2,b^2,c^2$,
which is sometimes more convenient than classic $\sqrt{\rho(\rho-a)(\rho-b)(\rho-c)}$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand it.